# CGRectIntegral & Monotouch

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

CGRectIntegral method in Objective C explained here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

how is mappend in monotouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RectangleF has an [Integral](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M:MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.RectangleFExtensions.Integral) extension method

```
public static System.Drawing.RectangleF Integral (this System.Drawing.RectangleF self)
```

Comment: @lipka This should have been a comment. Jason would then decide if he incorporates it into his post.